# UIPopOverControl and UIImageView

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiimageview, uipopovercontroller

I have created a `UIButton` and  `UIImageView` where the button frame is set  same as image frame size. What I'm willing  to do is once I touch the image it should `PopOver`. Button is set with action.The problem  is that it is displaying only image once I touch it is not Poping up.

What is wrong with my code?

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];    
    UIImageView *imageView=[[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(10, 10,100, 100)]; 
    imageView.image=[UIImage imageNamed:@"abc.jpg"];    
    [self.view addSubview:imageView];          
    imageView.userInteractionEnabled = YES;  
    UIButton *imageButton = [[UIButton alloc]init];
    [imageButton setFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 100, 100)];
    [imageButton addTarget:self action:@selector(imageTapped:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
    [imageView addSubview:imageButton];
    [imageButton release];
    [imageView release];     
}


-(void)imageTapped:(UIButton*)in_sender {
    UIViewController *popoverContent = [[UIViewController alloc] init];
    CGRect theScreenFrame = [[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds];
    popoverContent.view.frame = CGRectMake(theScreenFrame.origin.x, theScreenFrame.origin.y,100, 100);
    popoverContent.view.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
    popoverContent.contentSizeForViewInPopover = CGSizeMake(300, 300); 
    [popoverContent.view addSubview:imageButton];

    if(m_DetailPopover) {
        [m_DetailPopover release];
        m_DetailPopover = nil;
    }
    UIPopoverController m_DetailPopover = [[UIPopoverController alloc] initWithContentViewController:popoverContent];
    [popoverContent release];   

    [m_DetailPopover presentPopoverFromRect:imageButton.frame inView:self.view
     permittedArrowDirections:UIPopoverArrowDirectionAny  animated:YES];    
}
```

Comment: What is this imageButton object that you are referring to in imageTapped? An iVar? Property? What is its value?

Comment: yes imagebutton is referring to imagetapped

Comment: Yes. But why? Thats not gonna work the way you want.

Comment: Will it work if i declare the image to the button directly .I have tried it it is not working any other way?                                                           UIImage *image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"Chicken.jpg"];       
 UIBotton *button = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
 button.frame = CGRectMake(40, 40, 100,100);
 button.userInteractionEnabled = YES;
 [button setBackgroundImage:image forState:UIControlStateNormal];  
 [button addTarget:self action:@selector(imageTapped:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
 [self.view addSubview:button]

Comment: @mipe May i know what u actually edited?

Comment: Looks good to me. What does not work in your case? Don't you see he image or is the tourch up gesture not recognized? That is the way I did it several times and it just works for me.

Comment: @lokesh: Welcome to stack overflow. I have made just some formatting, no content change. Follow the link edited x hours/days ago, to see all revisions of your post. This is something you have to use to live with when you post on SO. There are people always eager to improve your post. ;-)

Answer (score 1):

Might be the problem is a typo in the code:

```
UIPopoverController *m_DetailPopover = [[UIPopoverController alloc] initWithContentViewController:popoverContent];
```

Also pls note that you cannot reference imageButton in imageTapped, because
you release it in viewDidLoad.

Answer (score 0):

Your UIImageView is front of the UIButton, not allowing to get the button action. Why don't you create a custom button with your image?

Do like this:

```
UIButton *imageButton = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
[imageButton setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"abc.jpg"]];
[imageButton setFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 100, 100)];
[imageButton addTarget:self action:@selector(imageTapped:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
[imageView addSubview:imageButton];
[imageButton release];
[imageView release];
```

**EDIT**

```
UIPopoverController *m_DetailPopover = [[UIPopoverController alloc] initWithContentViewController:popoverContent];


[m_DetailPopover presentPopoverFromRect:imageButton.frame inView:self.view
 permittedArrowDirections:UIPopoverArrowDirectionAny  animated:YES];  
[popoverContent release];
```

Comment: I thought the same but it is not the case. See `[imageView addSubview:imageButton];` The button is on top of the image. Well, I don't know why the button does not hide the image though. Anyway, he should get rid of the image view and deal with the button and image only.

Comment: But according to the frames you specified in the question, the Button has the same size as the ImageView, isn't it?

Comment: Have you already set a breakpoint at `-(void)imageTapped:(UIButton*)in_sender` to check if it's getting called?

Comment: @CainaSouza Ya i have set the breakpoint it is going to method but after that getting crash.

Comment: With your code, you're presenting the popover from the popover. It crashes! Check my answer. I edited

Comment: I'm trying it for iPhone not for ipad.Sorry not mentioned

Comment: Popover controllers are for use exclusively on iPad devices. Check Apple documentation http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIPopoverController_class/Reference/Reference.html

Comment: What you can do is use custom "popover" like this: http://www.cocoacontrols.com/platforms/ios/controls/mjpopupviewcontroller

Answer (score 0):

Dont' add an image view as subview to a button or vice versa. Just assign the image (not the image view) as background image to the button.